# Angular ngStyle show/hide condition not working

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to show hide my navbar on click of an image. On first click it is working, after that it doesn't. Not sure what is wrong. Any help please???

https://stackblitz.com/edit/responsive-menu-angular-material-flex-layout-cm87il

```
<img id="project-avatar" (click)="toggleNavbar()" width=20, height=20 style="position: relative;" alt="Show Hide Navigation Menu" src="/assets/img/slider_hide.png" />
<div> 

<div class="showHideNavbar" [ngStyle]="displayNavbar == '1' ? {'visibility': 'visible'} : {'visibility': 'hidden'}">
  <mat-toolbar color="primary" >
```

### component.ts

```
displayNavbar: string;

ngOnInit() {
    this.displayNavbar = '1';
}

toggleNavbar() {

    if(this.displayNavbar == '0') {
        this.displayNavbar = '1';
        alert(this.displayNavbar);
    } if(this.displayNavbar == '1') {
    //    alert("1 - Changing to 0");
        this.displayNavbar = '0';
    } else {
        this.displayNavbar = '1';
    }
}
```

1) Onload of the page the toolbar should show - it is showing as expected
[image]

2) On click of the icon(at top left corner), the toolbar should hide - it is working first time
[image]

3) On click of the icon again, the toolbar should display again - it is NOT working

https://stackblitz.com/edit/responsive-menu-angular-material-flex-layout-cm87il

Comment: This could be done easier with `[hidden]` and a boolean flag. Or alternatively `*ngIf`.

Comment: @AJT_82: Here is the stackblitz. if you can help me... https://stackblitz.com/edit/responsive-menu-angular-material-flex-layout-cm87il

Comment: As mentioned, here is using `[hidden]` and boolean flag instead. Much cleaner ;) https://stackblitz.com/edit/responsive-menu-angular-material-flex-layout-whwsn3?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Thanks a lot @AJT_82. It works nicely... :)

Comment: You are very welcome :)

Answer (score 7):

change

```
 [ngStyle]="displayNavbar == '1' ? {'visibility': 'visible'} : {'visibility': 'hidden'}"
```

to

```
 [ngStyle]="{'visibility': displayNavbar == '1' ? 'visible' : 'hidden'}"
```

or

```
[style.visibility]="displayNavbar == '1' ? 'visible' : 'hidden'"
```

change toggleNavbar function to

```
toggleNavbar() {
   this.displayNavbar = (this.displayNavbar == '1') ? '0' : '1'
}
```

[StackBlitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/responsive-menu-angular-material-flex-layout-4eyrbw)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what you said makes sense... but I am not sure why it is not working for me...

Comment: No, I have no class like that in any of my css

Comment: It needs to work, It is not about CSS. check this: https://embed.plnkr.co/jQVoTIpLqP6TeMVlqi6E/

Comment: I created this example with the issue.  https://stackblitz.com/edit/responsive-menu-angular-material-flex-layout-cm87il

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using 1 and 0 to toggle , try using true or false like the following which will simplify  code and render faster

> Component.ts

```
 displayNavbar: string;ngOnInit() {
    this.displayNavbar = false; // on init based on the logic set it to true or false
}

toggleNavbar() {
this.displayNavbar = ! this.displayNavbar; //toggle between true or false dynamically
}
```

> html

```
  <img id="project-avatar" (click)="toggleNavbar()" width=20, height=20 style="position: relative;" alt="Show Hide Navigation Menu" src="/assets/img/slider_hide.png" />
<div> 

<div class="showHideNavbar" [ngStyle]="(displayNavbar) ? {'visibility': 'visible'} : {'visibility': 'hidden'}">
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a property to your typescript file that holds the logic something like the following:

```
get showNavBar(): boolean {
    return this.displayNavBar === 1;
 }
```

Then you can use an *ngIf with that property to show or hide an element.

Comment: can you please guide me on that *ngIf part as well ?

Comment: It's not good practice to call function within html, because it will be called every change detection run, which can be very often

Comment: @SK. you can do something like this <div *ngIf="showNavBar"> and that div will only be displayed if showNavBar results in true.